Is there a simple name for a line segment joining the midpoints of 2 opposite edges of a regular hexagon?
What I already know:

A line segment between the midpoints of opposite edges of a square (or any quadrilateral) is called a bimedian.
A line segment between the midpoints of 2 edges of a triangle is called a midsegment.

What I would like to know:

Is there a general use word for a line segment connecting the midpoints of 2 sides of any shape? (In particular, I'd like to know the answer to the question in the title. We have words like diagonal and diameter, so I don't see why there wouldn't be a general word for lines between the midpoints of edges, but I can't seem to find one.)
Does the word bimedian make sense for any regular shape with an even number of sides, or does it only apply to quadrilaterals? [Answered]
Can the word midsegment be generalised for any shape, or does it only apply to triangles? (Failing everything else, I'm tempted to refer to this line as the long midsegment of the hexagon.)

Update: From looking into this on my own, I can now make the argument that bimedian is not an appropriate term for the line segment [between the midpoints of 2 opposite sides of a hexagon]. I was looking at what quadrilateral bimedians and triangle medians have in common to get some idea of what the words refer to.
I've read that for any triangle, the medians intersect in the centroid of the triangle, and they intersect at a point 1/3 of the way along each median. And in the case of any quadrilateral, the bimedians intersect in the centroid of the quadrilateral, and they intersect at a point 1/2 way along each bimedian. (Correct me if I'm wrong, but the fact that the intersection happens half way down the bimedian seems to be what the 'bi' is referring to.) To define a line as the bimedian of a hexagon, I would want to see this pattern continue (and be valid for any hexagon, the way it's valid for any square or any triangle). Unfortunately, there are irregular hexagons where the pattern doesn't work. I'm able to draw a hexagon where the 3 line segments [between the midpoints of opposite sides] don't share a single point of intersection, so they definitely don't fit the pattern for medians/bimedians.

I had never heard of bimedian or midsegment before today. But there are theorems that say something interesting about these segments, and the statements of the theorems are nicer if we have words for these things. Is there an interesting theorem that applies to your line segments? "Long midsegment" might then be exactly what you're looking for (although in a general hexagon you can have "short" midsegments much longer than one of the "long" midsegments, so maybe "long" is not what you want).

@DavidK Maybe you had a different word for it. Our book had "bisector" theorem which was exactly the midsegment theorem.

@DavidK I'll take note of the fact that hexagons can have longer midsegments than the one I want to describe. This is not to do with a theorem. Believe it or not, this has something to do with puzzle design.

@DavidK I'm only dealing with regular hexagons so the fact that irregular hexagons can have longer midsegments maybe doesn't matter actually. An irregular hexagon can have its longest diagonal be between non-opposite vertices, yet the 'long diagonal' of a regular hexagon is still understood to mean opposite vertices.

@jlanff: If your interest is only regular hexagons, then note that the segment joining opposite midpoints is a diameter of the polygon's incircle; aka, an indiameter . Also, half of such a segment —specifically, one joining the midpoint of a side to the center — is classically known as an apothem (despite also being an inradius); were I to coin a companion term, I might go with diapothem or biapothem.

@Blue I am a very big fan of diapothem as an intuitive new word. Why did you leave this as a comment and not an answer? Also the context around why I'm asking this question is purely related to regular hexagons. As long as I can describe these line segments on a regular hexagon, preferably in 1 word or 2, then I'm not bothered how it would work for irregular hexagons. I've only made an exception when I ruled out bimedian, because it seemed like the way medians worked on irregular shapes was a big part of what medians are.

@jlanff: I'll convert my comment to an answer. ... The community actually discourages answering in comments, but I can't seem to help myself. :) I guess I do it as a way to ensure that I understand the question and to check whether my input would be helpful. shrug

If your interest is only regular hexagons, then note that the segment joining opposite midpoints of a regular $2n$-gon is a diameter of that polygon's incircle; aka, an indiameter.
Note also that half of such a segment —specifically, one joining the midpoint of a side to the center— is classically known as an apothem (despite also being an inradius). Were I to coin a companion term, I might go with diapothem or biapothem, although it would only be defined for regular $2n$-gons.
Such a term would underscore the restriction with regular polygons, as well as the regular-figure-related properties of containing the polygon's center and lying perpendicular to its opposite sides. These connotations would be missing from a generalized "bimedian" or "midsegment".
